# How to convert from nchar to decimal in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables(source and destination) which are respectively **NOR_LABOR** and **ALL_LABOR_DETAILS**. In the source table(NOR_LABOR) there is a column "feet_produced" with the data type "nchar(10)". In the destination table(ALL_LABOR_DETAILS) there's a column "labor_feet_produced" with the data type "decimal(18,4)". I want to convert the "feet_produced" from nchar(10) to decimal(18,4) and paste it in the "ALL_LABOR_DETAILS" table's "labor_feet_produced" column.

I have found a code regarding a simillar issue but did not do the exact as I need to do, following is that code snippet :

```
Select feet_produced AS feet_produced_s, CASE WHEN Isnumeric(feet_produced) = 1
THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),feet_produced) 
ELSE 0 END AS feet_produced
INTO [MES_DEV].[dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS]
from [dbo].[NOR_LABOR]
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  "Paste" is not an operation in relational databases.

Answer (score 1):

There are values that will test true for `IS_NUMERIC`, but will fail to convert to decimal.

Instead, use `TRY_CONVERT` which will return either the successfully-converted-to-decimal value, or a `NULL` when it fails. (You can then `COALESCE` to zero to get your desired result).

Here is a short example set of values, using `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT 
        TryConvert = COALESCE(TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18,4),TestValues),0)
FROM (
        VALUES('10.6'),
              ('ten'),
              ('7d2'),
              ('10000000000'),
              ('10.00000001')
        ) AS x(TestValues);
```

The same set of values using your example code will throw an error:

```
SELECT 
        IsNumericCase = CASE 
                            WHEN Isnumeric(TestValues) = 1
                                THEN CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),TestValues) 
                            ELSE 0 
                        END
FROM (
        VALUES('10.6'),
              ('ten'),
              ('7d2'),
              ('10000000000'),
              ('10.00000001')
        ) AS x(TestValues);
```

This error is returned because 7d2 is [numeric, but cannot be converted to decimal](https://am2.co/2016/04/convert-float-using-scientific-notation/).

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 14
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what the issue is with the code that dose not work for you.

But here is how I would do it with a small change in the statement that you just post it.

```js
insert into[MES_DEV].[dbo].[ALL_LABOR_DETAILS](labor_feet_produced)
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 4), feet_produced) AS feet_produced_s from[dbo].[NOR_LABOR]
```